# zip files in linux corrupt in windows

Tags: php, zip

I use `pclzip` library to zip folders in linux, then open the file in the windows, the problem is occurred as follows:
[image]

```
$zipfile = new PclZip($destination);
$v_list = $zipfile->create($source, '', $source);
```

May someone have any idea about this problem?

Comment: What's in your $destination variable? Please check Question 5 of their FAQ http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/faq

Comment: Are you sending this zip directly to a browser with docx headers? If so, are there any echoes or print statements in your script that might be corrupting the output to php://output? Open the file in a text editor to see

Comment: @JonathanKortleven thanks for help, however, if  I use the same code to generate the file in the windows and download, open it ,it works ok

Comment: @MarkBaker pls refer to the my last comment. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanKortleven $destination variable is a docx word document path.

Comment: @JonathanKortleven I tried the Question 5's solution, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed the files from the ZIP archive before opening? Like extracting them to the desktop.

This is usually the cause of this.

Comment: After downloading, I remove the files.